# jQuery - Conflict between datepicker and searchable dropdown plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, datepicker

On a page I have a drop down list with `<select>` and  an `<input>` form for the date.

The dropdown list:

```
echo "<td>";
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT userName FROM users";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        echo "<select id='myselect' name='userName'>";
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='' disabled='disabled'></option>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if (isset($row['userName'])) {      
            echo "<option value='" . $row['userName'] . "'>" . $row['userName'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select>
        </td>
```

The date  form:

```
        <td>
        <input type='text' class='datepicker' name='entryDate'>
        </td>
```

For the date input form as you can see  I have a jQuery datepicker plugin, declared as follows:

```
<script src='../jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery/jquery-ui.js'></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
    });
</script>
```

This worked just fine, but then I wanted to add a jQuery plugin to make the dropdown list searchable. I found this plugin and added it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/sh/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/sh/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/sh/shCore.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/sh/shThemeDefault.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
<!-- END syntax highlighter -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").searchable();
    });


    // demo functions
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#value").html($("#myselect :selected").text() + " (VALUE: " + $("#myselect").val() + ")");
        $("select").change(function(){
            $("#value").html(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text + " (VALUE: " + this.value + ")");
        });
    });

    function modifySelect() {
        $("select").get(0).selectedIndex = 5;
    }

    function appendSelectOption(str) {
        $("select").append("<option value=\"" + str + "\">" + str + "</option>");
    }

    function applyOptions() {             
        $("select").searchable({
            maxListSize: $("#maxListSize").val(),
            maxMultiMatch: $("#maxMultiMatch").val(),
            latency: $("#latency").val(),
            exactMatch: $("#exactMatch").get(0).checked,
            wildcards: $("#wildcards").get(0).checked,
            ignoreCase: $("#ignoreCase").get(0).checked
        });

        alert(
            "OPTIONS\n---------------------------\n" + 
            "maxListSize: " + $("#maxListSize").val() + "\n" +
            "maxMultiMatch: " + $("#maxMultiMatch").val() + "\n" +
            "exactMatch: " + $("#exactMatch").get(0).checked + "\n"+
            "wildcards: " + $("#wildcards").get(0).checked + "\n" +
            "ignoreCase: " + $("#ignoreCase").get(0).checked + "\n" +
            "latency: " + $("#latency").val()
        );
    }
</script>
```

After adding the searchable dropdown list plugin `<select id='myselect' name='userName'>` the dropdown list became searchable as expected, but the datepicker stopped working. I noticed that if I delete the declaration of the searchable dropdown list plugin from the html `<head>` the datepicker works again.

Is there any reason why these two plugins conflict? And any solution?

Comment: What are the logs in console? Any errors? I see the code is fine, but some error may occur due to the new lib added

Comment: This?

`[30-Mar-2017 06:27:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_wincache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[30-Mar-2017 06:27:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_wincache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: not this. Check the browser console.

Comment: If I leave both plugins I get this error.

`TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function[Learn More]`

But if delete the searchable dropdown plugin, the datepicker works and this error disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

jQuery uses the $ sign as a shortcut for jQuery and this can cause conflicts with other scripts that also use the $ sign.

The solution comes from the jQuery noConflict() Method:

I replaced this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
```

With this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
});
```

For more details on noConflict method: [noConflict Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)